# How can i use vmrange label for calculate Percentage of requests less equal 500ms

Tags: charts, prometheus, grafana, promql, victoriametrics

I'm testing switching from prometheus to using victoria metrics.
In prometheus, my promQL:
`(sum(rate(demo_service_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le=\"0.5\"}[5m])) by (exported_job) / sum(rate(demo_service_request_duration_seconds_count[5m])) by (exported_job))`

And display like this:

[image]

But in victoria metrics not have "le" label to use.

How can i convert from old promQL for new promQL use vmrange label.

Tksssssss so much !!!!!

Comment: looks strange) what labels does `demo_service_request_duration_seconds_bucket` have?

Comment: @star67 like this:
demo_service_api_requests_total{code="200",method="GET"} 6
demo_service_in_flight_requests 0
demo_service_request_duration_seconds_bucket{code="200",method="GET",vmrange="4.642e-04...5.275e-04"} 1
demo_service_request_duration_seconds_bucket{code="200",method="GET",vmrange="1.136e-03...1.292e-03"} 1
demo_service_request_duration_seconds_bucket{code="200",method="GET",vmrange="1.468e-03...1.668e-03"} 1
demo_service_request_duration_seconds_bucket{code="200",method="GET",vmrange="1.668e-03...1.896e-03"} 2

Comment: You're probably looking for `histogram_share` function - https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_share

For instance, the following query returns the share of requests which are performed under 0.5 seconds during the last 5 minutes: histogram_share(0.5, sum(rate(demo_service_request_duration_seconds_bucket[5m])) by (vmrange))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following MetricsQL query:

```
histogram_share(0.5,
  sum(
    rate(demo_service_request_duration_seconds_bucket[5m])
  ) by (vmrange, exported_job)
)
```

It uses [histogram_share](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#histogram_share) function for returning the share of requests with the duration smaller or equal to 0.5 seconds during the last 5 minutes (see `5m` in square brackets). The share is returned individually per each `exported_job`. Every share is returned in the range `[0...1]`, where 0 means 0% of requests and 1 means 100% of requests.